# Sending FlashMessage to different BackendUser

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I know how to create flash messages in the backend and want to use this feature to my advantage to create an addition to the internal sys_notes. I can create flash messages for the current user by using something like this:

```
$flashMessage = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::class, 'This is some info flash message', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::INFO, true);
/** @var $flashMessageService \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService */
$flashMessageService = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService::class);
/** @var $defaultFlashMessageQueue \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageQueue */
$defaultFlashMessageQueue = $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier();
$defaultFlashMessageQueue->enqueue($flashMessage);
```

Now the question is: Can I create a flash message for a FlashMessage queue other than that of my current BackendUser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the extent of my knowledge: no, you cannot. FlashMessages get stored in your user session which means that in order to store a FlashMessage in another user's session, that session would have to be manipulated. There isn't any API to "set XYZ in user BAZ's session" - but maybe you could manually change the session record to queue a FlashMessage (simply go behind the normal way of dispatching).

I'm not sure I would do that, though. It could be risky to manipulate sessions this way. Normally I'd recommend using `sys_notes` instead but you already mention that you're trying to extend this exact component. If you end up deciding that it's too risky, perhaps consider implementing your own queueing which spools FlashMessages in a separate DB table and associates each message with a user or user group.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered `sys_notes` and they generally do exactly what I want, create a reminder for specific backend users by some automated functionality, but the sys notes are a little bit too "hidden" on the bottom of a pages list view. Generally they would do great, if I could move them to the top. The flash messages styling would fit great here. And I do not really want to mess with the sessions by myself, would have been great if there where a hidden API.

Comment: I completely agree it would be nice with at least one other method of rendering these system notes - as you said, they are almost invisible and only found in specific places (which you can even prevent users from accessing even though you didn't prevent access to notes). Maybe suggest this as a new feature, e.g. dispatching notes as persistent/ttl'ed flashmessages instead of listed notes?